# Determine what usage plan an API key belongs to - AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've searched for this for a while and have come up dry.

I'm curious if there's an AWS native way to find out the usage plan of an API key when all you have is the API Key.

We're looking to secure our API with AWS generated keys along with their usage plans, but would like to be able to access additional customer information from within the request.  For example, using some lookup function on the API key to figure out "this is API customer B, limit results to only items they own".

I've scoured the documentation, the SDK docs, as well as StackOverflow, and can't seem to find anything that would allow this.  Is there something simple I'm missing here?  I've also tried logging the context and event to try to find identifying parameters in a Lambda behind Api Gateway, but turned up empty handed.

I'm also **not** looking to roll my own key-identification system, unless there are existing products or libraries specifically designed for safely handling API keys.

Thanks in advance, and have a great day everyone!

Comment: You can add tags to the API Key. Would that help in any way?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried adding a tag to the Usage Plan, as the SDK doesn't seem to support adding tags directly to keys, but the tag didn't come through in any of the requests from Api Gateway to the Lambda.